# What is the category of this combination optimization problem?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I found this problem in "Barron-2400-SAT" book:

[image]

I thought the solution should be maximizing the usage of 60-cent stamps, but I got 8 stamps!

I can't find a systematic way to get the minimum number. I have to write all possible combinations manually which is pretty hard.

Is there a known category or method for this type of problem?

Comment: all I would note is that 60>2(37) so if you trade one of the 60 cent stamps out for two 37 stamps you get an overage to fix that you need to give up some of the 5 cent stamps in fact you have to give up 3. then there's 1 cent left over which is in 1 cent stamps.

Comment: I didn't understand. How could be 60>2(37) ??

Comment: Sorry clearly I messed up the symbols. 60<2(37), so you get an overage when you replace it, which needs to then be compensated for.